# AJAX request to get IP from URL

Tags: jquery

I have an url, let's say "www.google.com" and I want to know the corresponding IP. I have only javascript and jQuery at my disposal.

The following url : http://www.fileformat.info/tool/rest/dns.json?q=google.com once typed into the browser's address bar gives me this JSON result:

```
{"result":{"message":"OK","code":200},"answer":{"message":"successful","values":[{"address":"74.125.228.7","ttl":300},{"address":"74.125.228.3","ttl":300},{"address":"74.125.228.8","ttl":300},{"address":"74.125.228.9","ttl":300},{"address":"74.125.228.2","ttl":300},{"address":"74.125.228.0","ttl":300},{"address":"74.125.228.1","ttl":300},{"address":"74.125.228.4","ttl":300},{"address":"74.125.228.6","ttl":300},{"address":"74.125.228.14","ttl":300},    {"address":"74.125.228.5","ttl":300}],"code":0},"question":{"q":"google.com","type":"A"}}
```

Great, that's what I need!
But now, as I try to get the same result through this AJAX query

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.fileformat.info/tool/rest/dns.json?q=www.google.com',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(a,b) {
        console.log(a, b);
    }
});
```

The query returns a code 200, but then the error callback is trigged, why?

```
Object { readyState=4, status=404, statusText="error", more...} error
```

I'm surely missing something, but can't figure out what. I tried to set the 'dataType' to every possible values or to put the argument into the 'data' field, but nothing works. Is this some sort of cross origin issue ?

I will be happy if someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong, and how to achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
var addressArray = [];
for (x in data) {
   if (x == "answer") {
       var answer = data[x];
       for (y in answer) {

           if (y == "values") {
               var values = answer[y];
               for (z in values) {
                   var addressJson = values[z];
                   for (a in addressJson) {
                       if (a == "address") {
                           addressArray.push(addressJson[a]);
                        }

                   }

               }

           }

        }


   }


}
```

Comment: Now addressArray will contain all the IP

Comment: Well I know how to extract IPs from the JSON object, the problem is that I don't get the JSON object as an error is triggerd everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after lots of searching, I found out that it was a Cross Origin problem.
I solved it by using JSONP, i.e. I provided a callback function to the service.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp'
    url: 'http://www.fileformat.info/tool/rest/dns.json?callback=getIP&q=www.google.com',
});

function getIP(data) {
    console.log(data.answer.values[0].address);
}
```